# How to solve this in function of the remainder

Tags: analysis, number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I am trying to solve an exercise but I don't know how to do it at all :

> Given $m,n \in \mathbb N$ with $m>n>0$
>
> and $r = m \bmod n$
>
> Find ($2^m-1) \bmod (2^n-1)$ (as a function of $r$)

[(original image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GQvF.jpg)

I don't know at all where to start or what to do...

How can the value of the remainder help me to find the required result ?

Thank you.

Comment: If $m=n q+r$ with $0\leq r<n$ then $2^{n q}=1$ so $2^m-1=2^r-1 $ mod $2^n-1 $

Comment: See in particular [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/7561/242) for the key idea in the remainder calculation.